# How to generate grid system accept column with gutter and full width column in the same row

Tags: css, algorithm, grid-system

all I'm trying to build my own CSS Grid system, so basically I've applied the main algorithm to generate the columns which is

```js
var func =  (function (numberOfColumn){
var str = "",result = 0;

for (var i = 1 ; i < (numberOfColumn + 1); i++){
  result = (i/numberOfColumn) * 100;
  str += ".col-full-" + i + "{ width: "+ result + "%;}\n";
}
console.log(str);

}(12));
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0  0 0 0;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

[class^="col-"]{
    float:left;
    height: 50px;
    display:block;
    }
[class^="col-full-"]                            { margin-left:0; margin-right:0; }
body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
   background-color:#00ff21;
}

.row{
    width:100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    float: left; 
    clear: left;
}

.col-full-1{ width: 8.333333333333332%;}
.col-full-2{ width: 16.666666666666664%;}
.col-full-3{ width: 25%;}
.col-full-4{ width: 33.33333333333333%;}
.col-full-5{ width: 41.66666666666667%;}
.col-full-6{ width: 50%;}
.col-full-7{ width: 58.333333333333336%;}
.col-full-8{ width: 66.66666666666666%;}
.col-full-9{ width: 75%;}
.col-full-10{ width: 83.33333333333334%;}
.col-full-11{ width: 91.66666666666666%;}
.col-full-12{ width: 100%;}


.pink {

background-color:pink;
}

.red {
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-full-1 red"> col  1 </div>
        <div class="col-full-1 pink "> col  2 </div>
        <div class="col-full-1 red"> col  3 </div>
        <div class="col-full-1 pink "> col  4 </div>

        <div class="col-full-1 red"> col  5 </div>
        <div class="col-full-1 pink "> col  6 </div>
        <div class="col-full-1 red"> col  7 </div>
        <div class="col-full-1 pink "> col  8 </div>

        <div class="col-full-1 red"> col  9 </div>
        <div class="col-full-1 pink "> col  10 </div>
        <div class="col-full-1 red"> col  11 </div>
        <div class="col-full-1 pink "> col  12 </div>
        </div>
```

This part was simply completed, then I start the second part that is adding gutter to the columns I still using the percentage unit, so  I applied this algorithm to generate column with gutter.

```js
var func =  (function (numberOfColumn, GutterSize){
var totalNumberOfGutter = numberOfColumn + 1,
    totalSizeOfGutter   = totalNumberOfGutter * GutterSize,
    singleColumn        = ((1/numberOfColumn) * (100 - totalSizeOfGutter)),
    result              = 0,
    str                 = "";
    
for (var i = 1; i < numberOfColumn +1; i++){
    result = (singleColumn * i) + (GutterSize * (i-1));
    str += ".col-gut-" + i + "{ width: " + result + "%;}\n";
}
console.log(str);

}(12,1));
```

```css
*{    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0  0 0 0;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
    }

body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#00ff21;
}

.row{
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
    float: left; 
    clear: left;
}

[class^="col-"]{
    float:left;
    height: 50px;
    display:block;   
}

[class^="col-gut-"]                             { margin-left:.5%; margin-right:.5%; }
[class^="col-gut-"] + [class^="col-gut-"]       { margin-left:.5%; margin-right:.5%;} 

[class^="col-gut-"]:first-of-type  { margin-left:1%;  }
[class^="col-gut-"]:last-of-type   { margin-right:1%; }

.pink  {background-color:pink;}
.red   {background-color:red;}
.black {background-color:black;}

.col-gut-1{ width: 7.25%;}
.col-gut-2{ width: 15.5%;}
.col-gut-3{ width: 23.75%;}
.col-gut-4{ width: 32%;}
.col-gut-5{ width: 40.25%;}
.col-gut-6{ width: 48.5%;}
.col-gut-7{ width: 56.75%;}
.col-gut-8{ width: 65%;}
.col-gut-9{ width: 73.25%;}
.col-gut-10{ width: 81.5%;}
.col-gut-11{ width: 89.75%;}
.col-gut-12{ width: 98%; margin-left:1% !important; margin-right:1% !important;}
```

```html
<div class="row  black" >
        <div class="col-gut-1 red"> col gut 1 </div>
        <div class="col-gut-1 pink"> col gut 2 </div>
        <div class="col-gut-1 red"> col gut 3 </div>

        <div class="col-gut-1 red"> col gut 4 </div>
        <div class="col-gut-1 pink"> col gut 5 </div>
        <div class="col-gut-1 red"> col gut 6 </div>

        <div class="col-gut-1 red"> col gut 7 </div>
        <div class="col-gut-1 pink"> col gut 8 </div>
        <div class="col-gut-1 red"> col gut 9 </div>

        <div class="col-gut-1 red"> col gut 10 </div>
        <div class="col-gut-1 pink"> col gut 11 </div>
        <div class="col-gut-1 red"> col gut 12 </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row  black" >
        <div class="col-gut-2 red"> col gut 1 </div>
        <div class="col-gut-2 pink"> col gut 2 </div>
        <div class="col-gut-2 red"> col gut 3 </div>

        <div class="col-gut-2 red"> col gut 10 </div>
        <div class="col-gut-2 pink"> col gut 11 </div>
        <div class="col-gut-2 red"> col gut 12 </div>
    </div>
        <div class="row  black" >
        <div class="col-gut-4 red"> col gut 1 </div>
        <div class="col-gut-4 pink"> col gut 2 </div>
        <div class="col-gut-4 red"> col gut 3 </div>

    </div>
       
        <div class="row  black" >
        <div class="col-gut-3 red"> col gut 1 </div>
        <div class="col-gut-3 pink"> col gut 2 </div>
        <div class="col-gut-3 red"> col gut 3 </div>
        <div class="col-gut-3 pink"> col gut 2 </div>
    </div>
        <div class="row  black" >
        <div class="col-gut-6 red"> col gut 1 </div>
        <div class="col-gut-6 pink"> col gut 2 </div>

    </div>
      <div class="row  black" >
        <div class="col-gut-12 red"> col gut 1 </div>
        

    </div>
```

My problem is I'm trying to use full-column with gutter-column in the same row. I have tried to generate third category "pull", unfortunately, it hasn't been successfully. some possible answer would be resolve the problem using JavaScript, but I need a solution with pure CSS.

Comment: [**Don't Overthink It Grids**](https://css-tricks.com/dont-overthink-it-grids/)

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/115-dont-overthink-it-grids/

Comment: Here might be the problem in floats default float property you need to reset default property use Clearfix.

Comment: if that can solve the problem, can provide a practical answer ? Please go ahead.@Meraj Khan